# Вопрос по теме join

Tags: sql

Добрый день Я только начала изучать тему join. Наткнулась на такой пример:

```
    SELECT a.meaning prodgrp, b.meaning prod, b.price FROM produktgroup a, product b
    WHERE a.productgrp=b.productgrp;
```

Может мне пожалуйста кто-нибудь объяснить что это за тип join и какова его функция в этом примере?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: А где тут `JOIN` в примере, собственно?

Comment: @Simon `produktgroup a, product b` запятая это inner join

Comment: @andreymal Вы правы, не привык к такому синтаксису.

Comment: Это декартово произведение или CROSS JOIN: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_cartesian_product.html